# Css with conditional looping logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 divs and I have to apply the background for every of them according to this array of objects, like 1 div is green, gold and 2 divs are red. Brown should not be there as the tix_pax is zero. I know the method css() but didn't know how the looping logic work.

```
[
  {
    "tix_type": "adult",
    "bg": "gold",
    "tix_pax": 1
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "child",
    "bg": "brown",
    "tix_pax": 0
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "senior",
    "bg": "red",
    "tix_pax": 2
  },
  {
    "tix_type": "disabled",
    "bg": "green",
    "tix_pax": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: you can use `if` condition, depend the number of your loop.

Comment: can you share the html sample as well

Comment: @ArunPJohny number of div is dynamic, imagine it's like users' selection. so i can be also 10 divs, 3 is red, 5 for green, 2 is blue for example.

Comment: Did you view my solution? It would be more helpful if you gave a better description of how you want the divs to appear and a sample of the html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish something similar using Sass. Check here beginning at the "@for" section : http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Answer (score 0):

If you add an id property to this array of objects it would be easy to loop through, select each div separately and apply the corresponding color.

```
var objs = [
  {
    "id": "div1",
    "tix_type": "adult",
    "bg": "gold",
    "tix_pax": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "div2",
    "tix_type": "child",
    "bg": "brown",
    "tix_pax": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "div3",
    "tix_type": "senior",
    "bg": "red",
    "tix_pax": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "div4",
    "tix_type": "disabled",
    "bg": "green",
    "tix_pax": 1
  }
]

objs.forEach(function(ob) {
  var div = document.selectElementById(obj.id)
  div.style.backgroundColor = obj.bg
})
```

Comment: You need to create a div for each object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like

```js
var array = [{
  "tix_type": "adult",
  "bg": "gold",
  "tix_pax": 2
}, {
  "tix_type": "child",
  "bg": "brown",
  "tix_pax": 0
}, {
  "tix_type": "senior",
  "bg": "red",
  "tix_pax": 6
}, {
  "tix_type": "disabled",
  "bg": "green",
  "tix_pax": 2
}];


var pos = 0,
  $targets = $('.target');
array.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
  snippet.log('color elements between '+pos +' and ' + (pos+obj.tix_pax)+' as '+obj.bg)
  $targets.slice(pos, pos + obj.tix_pax).css('background-color', obj.bg);
  pos += obj.tix_pax;
});
```

```css
.target {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: @Jennifer http://api.jquery.com/slice/ - from the given jQuery object it will extract a new object with element between the given indexes

Comment: @Jennifer see the log in the result

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure how you want the div's to appear or where you want them placed in the page. You're data is valid JSON, so I just parsed it. I made a div '#container' and the code below will loop through your data and add the correct number of divs according to tix_pax with the background-color you want to the '#container' div if tix_pax is greater than zero

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Loopy</title>

<style>
.tix{
width:100px;
height:50px;
margin-right:10px;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var data = '[{"tix_type": "adult","bg": "gold","tix_pax": 1},{"tix_type": "child", "bg": "brown", "tix_pax": 0 },{"tix_type": "senior", "bg": "red", "tix_pax":2}, {"tix_type": "disabled","bg": "green","tix_pax": 1}]';

var $data = JSON.parse(data);

$.each($data, function(i, v){
    if(v.tix_pax>0){
        for (var i = 0; i < v.tix_pax; i++) {
            $('#container').append('<div class="tix" style="background-color:' + v.bg + ';"></div>');
        }
    }
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```